# Android Studio How to Get A Random Text When A Button Is Pressed

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, project

Can you help me to create a project in which user has to press a button, then it will give out some random names as a toast. That I have saved as a string in a string file

This is the activity main XML code for the button

```
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="Get Name" />
```

and this is the string.xml code for strings

```
<string name="app_name">test</string>
<string name="name1">Jhon</string>
<string name="name2">Chris</string>
<string name="name3">David</string>
```

However, I need help with the Java file and help with creating this project, please.
It is a very simple project. Just the user has to press a button and it should give a random name as a toast from my strings.

Comment: I would recommend storing the strings in a `<string-array>` resource instead of individual strings. Alternatively, you can declare an array of (hardwired) resource IDs in code. In either case, you then just pick an array element at random when you want a random string.

Answer (score 1):

Use the first of all make the string array in **string.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <string-array name="name">
     <item>Rishabh</item>
     <item>starboy</item>
     <item>jon</item>
     </string-array>
</resources>
```

**Then Java Code**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SimpleActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final Button button1 =  (Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);

    //Implement listener for your button so that when you click the 
    //button, android will listen to it.             

     button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {             
        public void onClick(View v) {                 
        // Perform action on click 
            String[] names = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.name);
            Random rand = new Random();
            int  n = rand.nextInt(names.length()-1);
            textView.setText(names[n]);

        }         });
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost. Use rand.nextInt(names.length()). The upper bound argument to nextInt() is exclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Make a StringArray and call random index

ex

```
String name[] = {"abc","def","ghj","abc","def","ghj"}
```

call in your button click

```
{
Random random = new Random();
// you have also handle min to max index 
int index = r.nextInt(name.length - 0) + 0;
tv.setText(name[index]);
}
```